Why am I receiving a 503 error when accessing my application through an AWS Application Load Balancer URL?
I'm deploying a Next.js (Docker image) application on AWS using Terraform, and I've set up an Application Load Balancer (ALB) to route traffic to my application running in an EKS cluster. However, I'm consistently receiving a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error when trying to access the application via the ALB's URL.
Here is the relevant part of my setup:

Application Load Balancer (ALB): Configured to forward HTTP traffic on port 80 to a target group.
Target Group: Points to EKS worker nodes running my Next.js application, listening on port 3000.
EKS Setup: Includes a deployment of the Next.js app, with a corresponding service that directs traffic to the correct pods.

Relevant Terraform configurations:

ALB Configuration (alb.internet_facing.tf):
resource "aws_lb" "internet_facing_alb" {
   name               = "internet-facing-alb"
   internal           = false
   load_balancer_type = "application"
   security_groups    = [aws_security_group.internet_facing_alb_sg.id]
   subnets            = module.vpc.public_subnets
   tags = {
     Environment = "${var.stage}"
   }
}


Listener Setup (alb.listener.app_nextjs.tf):
resource "aws_lb_listener" "http_listener" {
   load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.internet_facing_alb.arn
   port              = 80
   protocol          = "HTTP"
   default_action {
     type             = "forward"
     target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nextjs_tg.arn
   }
}


Target Group Setup (alb.tg.app_nextjs.tf):
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nextjs_tg" {
   name        = "${var.name}-nextjs-tg"
   target_type = "instance"
   port        = 3000
   protocol    = "HTTP"
   vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
}



Security Group Configuration:

Security Group for ALB(`sg.alb.internet_facing.tf):
# Security Group for Application Load Balancer (Public subnet)
resource "aws_security_group" "internet_facing_alb_sg" {
name        = "${var.stage}-alb-sg"
description = "Security group for Application Load Balancer"
vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

# ingress {
#   from_port   = 443
#   to_port     = 443
#   protocol    = "tcp"
#   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
# }

egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

tags = {
    Name = "${var.stage}-alb-sg"
}
}



Security Group for EKS Nodes(sg.k8s.eks.wk.node.tf):
# security_group listening traffic from alb nextjs_container_port
# Security Group for EKS Nodes
resource "aws_security_group" "eks_nodes_sg" {
name        = "${var.stage}-eks-nodes-sg"
description = "Security group for EKS Nodes"
vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

# Allow inbound traffic from the ALB to the application port (3000)
ingress {
    from_port       = 80                        # Should be the port that the ALB sends traffic to, typically 3000 if that's where your app listens
    to_port         = var.nextjs_container_port # The port your Next.js app is listening on
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.internet_facing_alb_sg.id]
}

# Allow all outbound traffic
egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

tags = {
    Name = "${var.stage}-eks-nodes-sg"
}
}





I suspect there might be an issue with how I've configured the security groups or the ALB listener rules, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Can anyone spot what might be causing the 503 error?
Additional Context ( Github Repo is also available )

EKS Service(deployment/k8s.service.nextjs.tf)
resource "kubernetes_service" "nextjs_service" {
metadata {
    name      = "nextjs-service"
    namespace = "ns-nextjs"  # Correct namespace name
    annotations = {
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type"                 = "alb"
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol"     = "http"
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-path"     = "/"
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-port"     = 80
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-interval" = 30
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-arn" = aws_lb_target_group.nextjs_tg.arn
    }
}

spec {
    selector = {
    app = var.nextjs_docker_app_name
    }

    port {
    protocol    = "TCP"
    port        = 80
    target_port = var.nextjs_container_port
    }

    # Uncomment below for SSL
    # port {
    #   protocol    = "TCP"
    #   port        = 443
    #   target_port = var.nextjs_container_port
    #   }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
}
depends_on = [module.eks]
}


EKS Deploument(k8s.app.deployment.nextjs.tf)
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nextjs_deployment" {
metadata {
    name      = "${var.stage}-nextjs-app"
    namespace = "ns-nextjs" # Correct namespace name
    annotations = {
    "nextjs-docker-image" = var.nextjs_docker_image
    }
}

spec {
    replicas = 2 # var.nextjs_replica_count
    selector {
    match_labels = {
        app = var.nextjs_docker_app_name
    }
    }

    template {
    metadata {
        labels = {
        app = var.nextjs_docker_app_name
        }
    }

    spec {
        container {
        image = var.nextjs_docker_image
        name  = var.nextjs_docker_app_name

        port {
            container_port = var.nextjs_container_port
        }

        resources {
            limits = {
            cpu    = "0.5"
            memory = "512Mi"
            }
            requests = {
            cpu    = "250m"
            memory = "256Mi"
            }
        }

        liveness_probe {
            http_get {
            path = "/"
            port = var.nextjs_container_port
            }
            initial_delay_seconds = 3
            period_seconds        = 3
        }

        readiness_probe {
            http_get {
            path = "/"
            port = var.nextjs_container_port
            }
            initial_delay_seconds = 30
            period_seconds        = 10
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
depends_on = [
    module.eks,
    kubernetes_service.nextjs_service
]

}




GitHub Repository: Link to GitHub repository.

When you create a Kubernetes service in EKS, it will automatically create a load balancer for you. With your configuration of k8s service, it seems it might create a new LB apart from the one you created with TF. Check with kubectl get svc for correct LB endpoint. Also, make sure your selector labels are consistent in deployments and service objects.

I would suggest first checking that you have the AWS Load Balancer Controller installed in your cluster, otherwise any of the annotation associated with it will have no effect, nor will you have any controller that is correctly set up to create/modify/attach LB's in your cloud environment. You can find the docs and guides here
As for the set-up - You are using an LB service within kubernetes which means you should use an NLB within AWS. If that is the correct and intended set-up you can find the annotations you can use and how here -- i.e. your
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type" = "alb" annotation will not have the desired effect when specified onto a k8s service.
The typical behaviour of the AWS LB Controller will be to create a new LB of the specified type based on the annotations whereas from what I can tell in your use-case you would like to create that yourself using TF code (that is not necessary btw - but perfectly fine if intentional) -- the caveat is that AFAIK NLBs cannot be attached as intended (only ALBs) check this.
Lastly, (and probably desired solution) if you intend on using ALB as configured above, you will have to create an Ingress for your application/service inside of Kubernetes and configure the correct annotations according to the docs and will consequently have to change the configuration of your service to ClusterIP or NodePort as you see fit as keeping it LB will not yield the desired results.
